# Is it possible to replicate the django admin into the app?

Tags: django, django-admin

Django provides a very useful admin interface but is it possible to replicate it inside the app as well to not writing extra code? I would only have to code the registration system but to use the django admin interface inside the app. Is it possible?

Comment: The admin is nothing but an interface to the database. It is generally not a good idea to expose this to the regular non-admin user. One thing you could do is, copy the template (https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html) and implement your features

Comment: Thanks. Just what I needed.